# tkinter delete multiple unselected items of a listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

i'm having some troubles deleting the unselected items of a listbox with tkinter,it works sometimes....but mainly fails,the problems is when you select more than one items and click on "Ocultar no seleccionats" button you must delete all the items that are not selected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#spyder
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import os, sys


def curdir():
    cdir = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=finestra, initialdir="/home")  
    v.set(cdir)       
def omplir():
    path=e1.get()
    dirs = os.listdir( path )
    for file in dirs:
        listbox.insert(END,file)
def reomplir():
    path=e1.get()
    listbox.delete(0,END)
    dirs = os.listdir( path )
    for file in dirs:
        listbox.insert(END,file)
def ons():
    ar=''
    c=0
    for i in listbox.curselection():
        ar=listbox.curselection()
    c=len(ar)
    listbox.delete(ar[c-1]+1,END)
    c=c-1
    while(c!=0):
        listbox.delete(ar[c-1]+1)
        c=c-1
    if ar[c]!=0:
        listbox.delete(0)
def oss():     
    ar=''
    for int in listbox.curselection():
        ar=listbox.curselection()
    i=len(ar)-1
    while(i>=0):
        listbox.delete(ar[i])
        i=i-1
def tots():

     for int in range(listbox.size()):
        ex=False
        for i in range(lbox.size()):
           if listbox.get(int) == lbox.get(i):
                ex=True
                break;
        if ex is False:
            lbox.insert(END,listbox.get(int))
def afg():
     for int in listbox.curselection():
        ex=False
        for i in range(listbox.size()):
           if listbox.get(int) == lbox.get(i):
                ex=True
                break;
        if ex is False:
            lbox.insert(END,listbox.get(int))
def dlt():
    ar=''
    for int in lbox.curselection():
        ar=lbox.curselection()
    i=len(ar)-1
    while(i>=0):
        lbox.delete(ar[i])
        i=i-1
def cap():
    lbox.delete(0,END)

#MAIN
finestra = Tk()
finestra.title("Creacio de fitxer comprimit")
f=Frame(finestra)
f.pack(side=TOP)

b=Button(f,text='Escollir directori treball',command=curdir)
b.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)

v=StringVar() 
v.set("/home")
e1=Entry(f,width=35,textvariable=v)

e1.pack(side=LEFT)

l1=Label(f,text="Fitxers a incorporar al fitxer tar:")
l1.pack(side=TOP,anchor=N,padx=120)


f1=Frame(finestra)
f1.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)

l2=Label(f1,text="Llista:")
l2.pack(side=LEFT)

br=Button(f1,text='Reomplir',command=reomplir)
br.pack(side=LEFT)
bo=Button(f1,text='Ocultar no seleccionats',command=ons)
bo.pack(side=LEFT)
bos=Button(f1,text='Ocultar seleccionats',command=oss)
bos.pack(side=LEFT)

Label(f1,text="\t\tCompresió").pack(side=LEFT)
rb1=Radiobutton(f1,text="cap").pack(side=LEFT)
rb2=Radiobutton(f1,text="gzip",value="gzip").pack(side=LEFT)
rb3=Radiobutton(f1,text="bzip2",value="bzip2").pack(side=LEFT)
rb4=Radiobutton(f1,text="xz",value="xz").pack(side=LEFT)


f2=Frame(finestra)
f2.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W,pady=0)


scrollbar = Scrollbar(f2)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill="y",expand=False)

listbox = Listbox(f2, bd=0, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,width=55,selectmode=EXTENDED)

listbox.pack(side=TOP,anchor=W,fill="both",expand=True)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

omplir()



f3=Frame(finestra)
f3.pack(side=LEFT)


Label(f3,text="Tots:").pack(side=TOP,anchor=W)
tots=Button(f3,text=">>>",command=tots).pack(side=TOP)
Label(f3,text="Als seleccionats:").pack(side=TOP)
af=Button(f3,text="-->",command=afg).pack(side=TOP)
qt=Button(f3,text="<--",command=dlt).pack(side=TOP)
Label(f3,text="Tots:").pack(side=TOP,anchor=W)
cap=Button(f3,text="<<<",command=cap).pack(side=TOP)

f4=Frame(finestra)
f4.pack(side=TOP)


sbar = Scrollbar(f4)
sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

lbox = Listbox(f4, bd=0, yscrollcommand=sbar.set,width=35,selectmode=EXTENDED)
lbox.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5)

sbar.config(command=lbox.yview)

f6=Frame(finestra)
f6.pack(side=TOP,anchor=W,padx=20)

Button(f6,text="Crea").pack(side=LEFT)
Label(f6,text="fitxer tar:").pack(side=LEFT)

f5=Frame(f2)
f5.pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=W)
Button(f5,text="Sortir",command=finestra.destroy).pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=S)












mainloop( )
```

Comment: What does "fails" mean? Does it throw an error? Does the program crash? Does it happen with any random selection or only specific selections?

Comment: it was randomly deleting items,not allways what i choose,was working with serial selection,but not with separated selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add all the words separated with a final whitespace,and then rebuild the listbox content.

```
def ons():
    cs=StringVar
    cs=""
    a=''
    for i in range(listbox.size()):
        if listbox.select_includes(i):
            cs +=listbox.get(i)+' ' #adding words ending with whitespace
    listbox.delete(0,END) #deleting all the listbox content
    for item in cs:
        a=a+item
        if item==' ': #full string passed
            listbox.insert(END,a) #insert selected item into listbox
            a=''#delete the string buffer
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't very useful. Your answer would be much better if you gave an explanation for what you did differently to solve the problem.

Comment: @Bryan oakley,you are right,was a little busy yesterday so i put a fast answer,here is a little explanation(hope that enought to understand what i did)

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to delete selected items:

```
def _del():
    n = 0
    for i in lb.curselection():
        lb.delete(i - n)
        n += 1

Button(f3, text='Del', relief=GROOVE, command=_del).pack(fill=X)
```

Also delete unselected items use this method，

```
def _delUsl():
    file_lsObj.set([lb.get(i) for i in lb.curselection()])
```

Comment: What is the question